# execute a function to place a file in unix

Tags: shell, unix

```shell
sftp_upload()   
{
  destination_server=$1 
  destination_path=$2
  destination_file_name=$3
  source_path=$4
  source_file_name=$5
  log_filename=$6
  port_number=$7

  if [ -z "$port_number" ] ; then 
    /usr/local/bin/sftp \
      $SFTP_OPTIONS \
        $SFTP_USERNAME@${destination_server} >> \
          ${log_filename} <<EOF 2>>${log_filename}
  else
    /usr/local/bin/sftp $SFTP_OPTIONS \
      -oPort=${port_number}$SFTP_USERNAME@${destination_server} >> \
        ${log_filename} <<EOF 2>>${log_filename}
  fi
lcd ${source_path}
cd ${destination_path}
put $source_file_name $destination_file_name
quit
fi
EOF
}
```

above function in the script gives an error missing '}' at line 101

My question is how to connect sftp in the if condition when the port number is not passed and if it is passed and how ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please observe that the script you show does not have 101 lines, so the error report for the script above does not say "line 101".  Yes, you get line 101 in the bigger script where you've written this code, but that doesn't help us — we don't have the bigger script.  It is easier for people if you either identify what is line 101 in your big script or you give the line number in exactly what you paste into the question.  That might mean creating an MCTRE [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

A `here document` always starts directly after the command with the `<<EOF` redirection.
Therefore, your `else` ... `fi` get swallowed by the `here-document`.

Move the command outside of the if statement:

```shell
sftp_upload () {

  destination_server=$1 
  destination_path=$2
  destination_file_name=$3
  source_path=$4
  source_file_name=$5
  log_filename=$6
  port_number=$7
  PORT=""

if [ -n "$port_number" ] ; then
    PORT="-oPort=${port_number}"
fi

  /usr/local/bin/sftp \
    $SFTP_OPTIONS \
      $PORT \
        ${SFTP_USERNAME}@${destination_server} >> \
          ${log_filename} 2>&1 <<EOF
lcd ${source_path}
cd ${destination_path}
put $source_file_name $destination_file_name
quit
fi
EOF
}
```

If `$PORT` is empty, the `sftp` command will just connect on the default port (22) instead.